# batch: set variable and compare it with another

Tags: bash, batch-file

Task: check a number of files and directories in directory under **Windows** OS. If the number is equal to some number, then return 0. If not, return 1 and exit with error.

In `bash` on **Linux**, it might look like this:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=`ls -l | wc -l`
[[ $a -eq 5 ]] || { echo "$a NOT equal to 6"; exit 1; }
echo "$a equal to 6"
```

And:

```
$ ls -l | wc -l
6
```

And:

```
$ ./a.sh
6 NOT equal to 6
```

How I can do same for **Windows**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off 
  setlocal
  set "number=6"
  dir /b|find /c /v ""|findstr /x /c:"%number%">nul && (echo equal to %number% & endlocal & exit /b 0)
  echo not equal to %number% & endlocal & exit /b 1
```